# Magento 2 setup:di:compile not work

Tags: magento2, php, setup-di-compile, command

When i try to start command setup:di:compile i see this error:

[image]

and this is the file FileClassScanner.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader;

/**
 * Class FileClassScanner
 *
 * @package Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader
 */
class FileClassScanner
{
    private const NAMESPACE_TOKENS = [
        T_WHITESPACE => true,
        T_STRING => true,
        T_NS_SEPARATOR => true
    ];

    private const ALLOWED_OPEN_BRACES_TOKENS = [
        T_CURLY_OPEN               => true,
        T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES => true,
        T_STRING_VARNAME           => true];

    /**
     * The filename of the file to introspect
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * The list of classes found in the file.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $classNames = false;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $tokens;

    /**
     * Constructor for the file class scanner.  Requires the filename
     *
     * @param string $filename
     */
    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        // phpcs:ignore
        $filename = realpath($filename);
        // phpcs:ignore
        if (!file_exists($filename) || !\is_file($filename)) {
            throw new InvalidFileException(
                sprintf(
                    'The file "%s" does not exist or is not a file',
                    $filename
                )
            );
        }
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the contents of a file.  Mostly here for Mock injection
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileContents()
    {
        // phpcs:ignore
        return file_get_contents($this->filename);
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the fully qualified class name from a file.
     *
     * It only searches for the first match and stops looking as soon as it enters the class definition itself.
     *
     * Warnings are suppressed for this method due to a micro-optimization that only really shows up when this logic
     * is called several millions of times, which can happen quite easily with even moderately sized codebases.
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @return array
     */
    private function extract()
    {
        $classes = [];
        $namespaceParts = [];
        $class = '';
        $triggerClass = false;
        $triggerNamespace = false;
        $braceLevel = 0;
        $bracedNamespace = false;

        // phpcs:ignore
        $this->tokens = token_get_all($this->getFileContents());
        foreach ($this->tokens as $index => $token) {
            $tokenIsArray = is_array($token);
            // Is either a literal brace or an interpolated brace with a variable
            if ($token === '{' || ($tokenIsArray && isset(self::ALLOWED_OPEN_BRACES_TOKENS[$token[0]]))) {
                $braceLevel++;
            } elseif ($token === '}') {
                $braceLevel--;
            }
            // The namespace keyword was found in the last loop
            if ($triggerNamespace) {
                // A string ; or a discovered namespace that looks like "namespace name { }"
                if (!$tokenIsArray || ($namespaceParts && $token[0] === T_WHITESPACE)) {
                    $triggerNamespace = false;
                    $namespaceParts[] = '\\';
                    continue;
                }
                $namespaceParts[] = $token[1];

            // The class keyword was found in the last loop
            } elseif ($triggerClass && $token[0] === T_STRING) {
                $triggerClass = false;
                $class = $token[1];
            }

            switch ($token[0]) {
                case T_NAMESPACE:
                    // Current loop contains the namespace keyword.  Between this and the semicolon is the namespace
                    $triggerNamespace = true;
                    $namespaceParts = [];
                    $bracedNamespace = $this->isBracedNamespace($index);
                    break;
                case T_CLASS:
                    // Current loop contains the class keyword.  Next loop will have the class name itself.
                    if ($braceLevel == 0 || ($bracedNamespace && $braceLevel == 1)) {
                        $triggerClass = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            // We have a class name, let's concatenate and store it!
            if ($class !== '') {
                $fqClassName = trim(join('', $namespaceParts)) . trim($class);
                $classes[] = $fqClassName;
                $class = '';
            }
        }
        return $classes;
    }

    /**
     * Looks forward from the current index to determine if the namespace is nested in {} or terminated with ;
     *
     * @param integer $index
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isBracedNamespace($index)
    {
        $len = count($this->tokens);
        while ($index++ < $len) {
            if (!is_array($this->tokens[$index])) {
                if ($this->tokens[$index] === ';') {
                    return false;
                } elseif ($this->tokens[$index] === '{') {
                    return true;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (!isset(self::NAMESPACE_TOKENS[$this->tokens[$index][0]])) {
                throw new InvalidFileException('Namespace not defined properly');
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidFileException('Could not find namespace termination');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the first class found in a class file.
     *
     * The return value is in an array format so it retains the same usage as the FileScanner.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getClassNames()
    {
        if ($this->classNames === false) {
            $this->classNames = $this->extract();
        }
        return $this->classNames;
    }
}
```

I tried to search but i have not found anything abaout this issue.
How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: please share this file

Comment: Ok man, i shared this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is throwing error

```
if (!isset(self::NAMESPACE_TOKENS[$this->tokens[$index][0]])) {
    throw new InvalidFileException('Namespace not defined properly');
}
```

`isset` code is not validating, you need to debug the value of `$this->tokens[$index][0]`,

Change this code to this, in order to debug the value

```
if (!isset(self::NAMESPACE_TOKENS[$this->tokens[$index][0]])) {
    throw new InvalidFileException('Namespace not defined properly. Key: '.$this->tokens[$index][0]);
}
```

Comment: I tried man and i have this error: Namespace not defined properly. Key: 320

Comment: Your edit helped me for find solution. The problem was in my custom class. Thanks ;)

Comment: Good to hear that you have resolved the issue :)

Comment: @ShoaibMunir, yes it return key number (353), what is the mean?

Comment: i just change index to 1 and i found classname which have issue and i solved my issue --  throw new InvalidFileException('Namespace not defined properly. Key: '.$this->tokens[$index][1]);

Answer (score 0):

Use below code after if condition

```
if (!isset(self::NAMESPACE_TOKENS[$this->tokens[$index][0]])) {
                echo $this->getFileContents();
```